# Postgresql operations on columns

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate daily income for working people. I made a postgresql database with pgadmin III and postgresql 9.5.8 where people can enter the date, the start time and end time for each day and the rate hour. From those information, I would like the database to calculate the working time (start - end) and the daily income (working time * rate hour). Would have any ideas how could I do that on pgadmin III ? I know how to do it when I am using the query function, but I don't want it to be as a query but as column in the database. Is it possible ? Thank you. [image: postgresql database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a table where some of the columns have calculated values based on other columns.

One way to do this is to use a [View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createview.html). It can be used like a regular table but it's column values are only calculated when you use it in some query.

Assuming an `example` table with columns `start_hour`, `end_hour` and `rate`,
here's a simple view based on your explanation:

```
CREATE VIEW example_view AS
SELECT
  start_date, start_hour, end_hour, rate,
  (end_hour-start_hour) AS work_time,
  (end_hour-start_hour) * rate AS daily_income
FROM example;
```

You can use it like with a regular table (select form it, join to it other tables, etc). Here's [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb780/1) with the example, and also a similar view without the duplicated logic for the `work_time` calculation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very helpful !